# Refactor Controller Code for LIst Sorting Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

List sorting using sort column. Function is working well, however I feel like there must be a way to refactor this code, as the only difference is the operators for some variable assignments!

Methods used to be separate so managed to reduce the code slightly, but not enough!

One method will move the item up in the list, and the down method will move the list item down one. Swap method is to switch the positions in the list.

I have the order set in the model scope

```rb
  def up
    return false if @dish == @section.dishes.first
    swap('up', @dish, @section)
  end

  def down
    return false if @dish == @section.dishes.last
    swap('down', @dish, @section)
  end

  def swap(direction, dish, section)
    dish_i = 0
    section.dishes.each_with_index do |d, i|
      dish_i = i - 1 if dish == d && direction == 'up'
      dish_i = i + 1 if dish == d && direction == 'down'
    end
    dish2 = section.dishes[dish_i]
    if direction == 'up'
      dish2.sort += 1
      dish.sort -= 1
    elsif direction == 'down'
      dish2.sort -= 1
      dish.sort += 1
    end
    if @dish.save && dish2.save
      redirect_to menu_path(params[:menu_id])
    else
      render :show
    end
  end
```

would like to reduce the code as a lot of the logic is the same

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem, which is mature, well-tested, and designed for this exact purpose.

That said, I think you're probably overthinking this slightly. You don't need to do all of that math, nor do you need to fetch all of the other Dishes in the Section. All you need to do is fetch the Dish with the next higher/lower `sort` and swap the two Dishes' `sort`s:

```
def up
  swap!(:up, @dish, @section)
end

def down
  swap!(:down, @dish, @section)
end

def swap!(direction, dish, section)
  condition = direction == :up ? 'sort > ?' : 'sort < ?'
  asc_or_desc = direction == :up ? :desc : :asc
  next_dish = section.dishes
    .where(condition, dish.sort)
    .order(sort: asc_or_desc)
    .first

  return false if next_dish.nil?

  Dish.transaction do
    next_dish.update!(sort: dish.sort)
    dish.update!(sort: next_dish.sort)
  end
end
```

On the topic of organizing your code, the code `redirect_to` and `render` code should go in your controller method (e.g. `update`), not `swap`. And for that matter, all of the code above probably belongs in your model, not your controller:

```
class Dish < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  def move_up!(section)
    swap!(:up, section)
  end

  def move_down!(section)
    swap!(:down, section)
  end

  def swap!(direction, section)
    condition = direction == :up ? 'sort > ?' : 'sort < ?'
    asc_or_desc = direction == :up ? :desc : :asc
    next_dish = section.dishes
      .where(condition, sort)
      .order(sort: asc_or_desc)
      .first

    return false if next_dish.nil?

    transaction do
      next_dish.update!(sort: sort)
      update!(sort: next_dish.sort)
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller method you would just call e.g. `@dish.move_up!(@section)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response and suggestions. I had trouble using the act_as_list gem as I am using HABTM relationships between the models which doesn't seem to be compatible.

Your code is great, only part I don't understand is this: 'sort > ?' in the ternary operator. What is the use of the ? in this case?

Also my update method currently is accepting params which it is receiving from a form for editing the text. Can I still use the same update method when only wanting to update the sort column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more minimal form of this, but this general-purpose method might be the basis for a start. This uses the array modifier where chunks of the array can be given the `reverse` treatment to swap their order:

```
def swap(list, el, dir)
  index = list.index(el)
  list = list.dup

  case (dir)
  when :up
    # Do simple bounds checking here
    unless (index > 0)
      return list
    end

    # Offset the swap
    index -= 1

  when :down
    unless (index + 1 < list.length)
      return list
    end
  end

  # Reverse the elements at the target location
  list[index, 2] = list[index, 2].reverse

  list
end
```

You'll want to keep your `render` and `redirect_to` calls out of your `swap` method so it does *one thing and one thing only*. You're over-complicating the method by making it do a bunch of things at once and this makes it hard to test.

This one here can be demonstrated easily:

```
list = %w[ a b c d e f ]

p swap(list, 'a', :down) # => ["b", "a", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
p swap(list, 'a', :up)   # => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
p swap(list, 'c', :down) # => ["a", "b", "d", "c", "e", "f"]
p swap(list, 'c', :up)   # => ["a", "c", "b", "d", "e", "f"]
p swap(list, 'f', :down) # => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
p swap(list, 'f', :up)   # => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "e"]
```